# How can I clear current woocommerce cart after clicking on "Complete order via WhatsApp"?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, whatsapp

I'm currently using the OneClick Chat to Order plugin on my wordpress site to complete the order through WhatsApp. Everything works fine, but after clicking on "Complete order via WhatsApp" the cart won't clear and the items will remain until I remove them manually.

I tried the method `WC()->cart->empty_cart()`; for cart items on `whatsapp-order.php` under "buttons", but it will trigger on page refresh and for all sessions (my site doesn't use user login). I want it to work only after clicking "Complete order via WhatsApp" and for the current session.

Some help will be highly appreciated.

```php
$items = WC()->cart->empty_cart();
```

Comment: This seems a bug from, OneClick Chat to Order plugin. Don't change the plugin core files (as you will lose your changes when the plugin is updated), instead, [contact the plugin author's support](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/oneclick-whatsapp-order/) and report this bug.